# Different menus for mobile/desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so I'm using Bootstrap and working on different menus for desktop/tablet and mobile. I have a regular top-fixed navbar for desktop/tablet and a couple of the tabs are drop-down menus with multiple columns making it illogical to use this for mobile, so I'm doing a slide push menu for that. Can anyone point me in the general direction of how to do so efficiently? I know how to implement the menus themselves, it's just facilitating which is shown for their respective devices. Would I need to use media queries and **display:none** for the respective menus, or possibly a JS if statement? Would the latter cause mobile versions to load the site slower to a point where it isn't feasible as the other menu is extensive?

I've searched SE, and found an answer but it was for WP only so didn't really help, but it utilized an if statement. Thanks for your help!

Comment: media queries and display none is a reasonable approach

Comment: Ok perfect, thanks for the help everyone, just had to clear that up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Bootstrap, there are class that you can use to tell a part is hidden depending on the screen's width.

These class are `hidden-xs`, `hidden-sm` and so on.

See this on the bootstrap documentation : 
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Answer (score 2):

Using `display : none` with media queries will do the job and wont cause any problem in the mobile version.